# C++ array exported to Excel is column-major

Tags: c++, excel, vba

The following results in unexpected column-major order in an array exported from C++ to Excel.

We create a 3-row, 2-column array in Excel VBA. Its address is then supplied to the C++ dll as a pointer. In C++ the array is populated and is then available to Excel.

The expected result is a row-major array:

```
0 1
2 3
4 5
```

but the actual output is column-major:

```
0 3
1 4
2 5
```

Can anyone explain why this happens and is there a way around it (other than changing the input order in C++ to 0, 2, 4, 1, 3, 5)?

In VBA

```vb
Option Explicit

Declare PtrSafe Function get_array_from_C Lib _
"C:\path\DLL_1.dll" (ByRef dOut As Double) As Long

Sub GetArrayFrom_C()

 Dim adRet() As Double
 Dim iError As Integer

 ReDim adRet(1 To 3, 1 To 2)

 iError = get_array_from_C(adRet(1, 1))

 Worksheets(1).Cells(1, 1).Resize(3, 2).Value2 = adRet

End Sub
```

In C++

```
int __stdcall get_array_from_C(double* dOut)
{
    dOut[0] = 0;
    dOut[1] = 1;
    dOut[2] = 2;
    dOut[3] = 3;
    dOut[4] = 4;
    dOut[5] = 5;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: you are working with a SAFEARRAY and it appears poking values in directly.  Why not use the libraries? like ATL?  I'm surprised the code  runs.

Comment: All the values from the first dimension are aligned in memory. It's an expected behavior since Excel uses the first dimension to represent the row. Either transpose the values on the VBA side or C++ side.